# Microsoft word: bullet lists with custom spacing

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016

I am creating a list in Microsoft Word, where each bullet has several sub-bullets. I would like to format this list so that before each new bullet, there is a large space, but there is no large space between sub-bullets. See the example in the picture below.

[image: bullet example]

The formatting done in this picture was done by manually selecting each bullet and changing the formatting to add spacing before the line. However, I would like to make this automatic. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use different paragraph spacing for your 2 different bullet styles - for the main level, you'd have a larger Spacing Before setting eg 18pt, and for the sub-bullet style you might have 0 spacing before and after.

Comment: @Tanya But is there a way to do this so I don't have to continuously adjust the spacing if I decide to add new bullets?

Comment: Are you using a style for your bullets?  I use specific custom styles for bullets, and assign a shortcut key to make it even easier to apply.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that was a thing; could you point me to a resource for how to make custom bullet styles?

Comment: Just the same as setting up outline numbered styles.  I'd set up new separate paragraph styles for each level of bullets eg Bullet L1, Bullet L2, Bullet L3.  Then define a new List Style on the Define New List Style dialog, and via the Format button at bottom left of that dialog, select Numbering to bring up the Modify Multilevel List dialog where you can link the levels to your new Bullet styles and set the bullet icon (from the dropdown list for numbering).  For the space before, you'd modify the actual Bullet L1 style paragraph settings separately.